# Which folder/file are "Item Sets" saved in?

Tags: league-of-legends

"Item Sets" are a really big improvement on League of Legends client, but the data is saved on the local disk.

I want to backup my file/folder, so I can (hopefully) transfer my builds to other PCs. Copying the entire LoL folder is impractical (more than 4GB).

Which folder/file are "Item Sets" saved in?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> `{your install dir}\Riot\League of Legends\RADS\projects\
>   lol_air_client\releases\0.0.1.16\deploy\preferences\{your name}.properties`

```
NOTE: 2013-05-18 latest patch it's now "0.0.1.18"
```

This is the location and filename of the file that gets edited whenever I change an itemset. This is of course only as current as of today and might change with newer patches.

Comment: Note that this includes all preferences, not just item sets. Item sets are a portion of it; I think a 3rd-party utility could be written to import/export them -- maybe I will! :P

Comment: 0.0.1.68 on my laptop, as of today (24/01/14)

Comment: I can't submit it as edit, but could you instead display the path in code block?

Comment: I intercepted the format and it's a mess of binary and ascii data. The itemsets, however, are contained in a JSON string within the `.properties` file.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer BTSync synchronizing the .properties file between computers in the "My Games" folder, along with a batch script that finds the latest release path, and copies it in when run. If the .properties in the riot dir is newer, it copies that into the "My Games" folder.